# How to retrieve custom properties created by Outlook add-in using EWS?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I've created a custom property through a calendar Outlook add-in (JS add-in). I'm unable to get this custom property using the EWS API.

I've followed the various examples on how to retrieve add-in custom properties with no luck. I know that the custom property is properly saved because I'm able to retrieve the custom property using the add-in after initially saving and I'm able to use the MS Graph Explorer to query the specific item and confirm that the custom property is saved somewhere.

```
val addinProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
      UUID.fromString("00020329-0000-0000c000-000000000046"),
      "cecp-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
      MapiPropertyType.String
    )

val propertiesToLoad = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, addinProp)

val appointmentWitNewProp = Appointment.bind(service, itemEvent.getItemId, propertiesToLoad)
```

I expect the bind call to retrieve the specific item and the provided property set. All other properties are successfully returned except for the custom property.

Comment: Do you see your custom property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) or MFCMAPI? Make sure the guid and id are correct.

Comment: Yes I do. The custom property is saved because I can retrieve it using the Office.js `loadCustomPropertiesAsync` method after saving them.

Comment: Your approach looks correct.  There are a few things to double check: 1. the properties has been sync-ed back to Exchange (you would have confirmed that by checking with Graph Explorer first and then running your code).  2. Confirm that there are no typos or easy-to-miss issues - make sure your itemId matches, and make sure the generated EWS XML, especially for the extended property definition matches the property from the Graph Explorer result (same property set, same property name)